# Конкатенация числа к элементам матрицы

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть матрица

```
[[0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 1, 0], 
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1], 
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Как мне к каждому его элементу добавить значение, чтобы получилось вот так&?

```
[[20, 21, 21, 21, 20],
 [21, 20, 21, 20, 21],
 [21, 21, 20, 21, 20], 
[21, 20, 21, 20, 21], 
[20, 21, 20, 21, 20]]
```

Comment: а в чем сложность? добавить 20 к каждому элементу...

Answer (score 6):

```py
x = [[0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 1, 0], 
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1], 
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]

for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(x[i])):
        x[i][j] += 20
```

вы это имели в виду?

Answer (score 5):

Для обработки матриц можно использовать специально для этого разработанные модули: [Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/quickstart.html) или [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

Пример (Numpy):

```
In [3]: import numpy as np    #  pip install numpy

In [4]: a = np.array(m)

In [5]: a
Out[5]:
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])

In [6]: a += 20

In [7]: a
Out[7]:
array([[20, 21, 21, 21, 20],
       [21, 20, 21, 20, 21],
       [21, 21, 20, 21, 20],
       [21, 20, 21, 20, 21],
       [20, 21, 20, 21, 20]])
```

---

Пример (Pandas):

```
In [12]: import pandas as pd    #  pip install pandas

In [13]: df = pd.DataFrame(m)

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
   0  1  2  3  4
0  0  1  1  1  0
1  1  0  1  0  1
2  1  1  0  1  0
3  1  0  1  0  1
4  0  1  0  1  0

In [15]: df += 20

In [16]: df
Out[16]:
    0   1   2   3   4
0  20  21  21  21  20
1  21  20  21  20  21
2  21  21  20  21  20
3  21  20  21  20  21
4  20  21  20  21  20
```

Comment: Не совсем так, нужно 2-ку прикреплять к 20, 21, 21, 21, 20],
 [21, 20, 21, 20, 21],
 [21, 21, 20, 21, 20], 
[21, 20, 21, 20, 21], 
[20, 21, 20, 21, 20] К исходной матрицы

Comment: @ДмитрийЮзов, что значит прикреплять? Т.е. если повторить операцию то должно получиться [[220, 221, ...] ?